# Get DataKey value of nested gridview on when on LinkButton click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a nested gridview. How can i get a DataKey value when linkbutton is clicked inside the nested gridview. Below code is only working for gridview not for nested gridview.
Parent GridView name is GridView 1, and child name is GridView2

```
protected void lbCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv = (GridView)clickedRow.FindControl("GridView2");
    string lbCode = gv.DataKeys[clickedRow.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: use `foreach()`

Comment: which is contain link button?

Comment: isn't this `clickedRow ` belongs to nested grid? why are you using this on main grid's row index? you can also add command arguement with id on this link button while filling the nested grid.

Comment: yeah @ARr0w says correctly try that ,not need to write `lbCode_Click` ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both the LinkButton in the GridView and in the Nested Gridview use `lbCode_Click`, you need to find the GridView belonging to the LinkButton that has been clicked in order to get the correct DataKey.

So use `NamingContainer` again on the `GridViewRow`

```
protected void lbCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    GridView gv = clickedRow.NamingContainer as GridView;
    string lbCode = gv.DataKeys[clickedRow.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks its save my time. @VDWWD